# Can one follow "old" kitniyot rules?

Tags: minhag, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Years ago, during 60's and 70's OU certified the [use of peanut oil](https://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/nuts/), corn oil and seeds. Miller's kimmel muenster (muenster with caraway seeds) was OU certified. I also believe that sesame candies were certified as well.

At one time, legume derivatives (oils) and seeds were not considered kitniyot for Ashkenazim. AT some point, this rule has changed.

If someone is observing kitniyot rules on Pesach, but followed the minhag based on these previous rulings for many years, can he follow these rulings now as well? Can his children or spouse follow his minhag as being the household minhag, as well?

Comment: "AT [sic] some point, this rule has changed." You have brought no support for that.

Comment: Are you asking about in theory or in practice? In practice, the article that you linked answers the question directly: "Furthermore, we cannot recommend that people whose custom is to use peanut oil on Passover use un-certified peanut oil, because of concerns about the peanut oil being processed on non-Passover equipment." So even if your practice is to eat peanut oil, you'd have to find some that is certified for Passover use.

Comment: @Daniel Theory. The answer, below, is OK for me. I should accept it, shouldn't I :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the subject of this morning's daily halacha at shul, given by the town's rabbi. He said that since we have no chazakah of "new" kitniyot (such as flax seed) being assur, it is permissible to use them, unless someone's family minhag is not to.
He quoted [Rav Dov Lior's ruling](http://www.srugim.co.il/30698-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%93%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%92%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%95%D7%98) that only those items that were on the original list are banned, unless someone has a minhag not to use something. I believe Rav Moshe Feinstein paskened this way as well, but i cannot find the source online.
This would mean that, in theory, corn could be allowed, but because nearly everyone has taken on the minhag of not eating it for the past several centuries, it is banned under the second clause.

So in your example, if someone has the custom of using peanut oil, that is his family's custom, and it is permitted for them.

Note that i have only brought support for allowing it. There are also rabbis who ban "new" products. CYLOR.